# Do these Topologies define the same open sets?

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

I am trying to understand weak Topologies by reading John Conway's Course in Functional Analysis and he lists a bunch of theorems such as:

"If $X$ is LCS, $(X,wk)^{*} =X^{*}$"

which are getting very confusing and as he calls it, an exercise in notational juggling. To better understand this, I am trying to make my own example, but I am already getting lost.

Let $X$ be a normed space, then the dual, $X^{*}$ is a Banach space.

I've read that if $X$ is merely a locally convex space, then $X^{*}$ isn't necessarily a Banach space and so the only reasonable topology to endow $X^{*}$ with is the $wk^{*}$ topology. However, if $X$ is a normed space, it seems reasonable that we can endow $X^{*}$ with a norm topology.

If we consider $X$ normed, generate a topological space from it $X^{*}$ and endow $X^{*}$ with its norm topology, call it $Y:= (X^{*}, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$. Then suppose we take $Y$ as its own Banach space, momentarily forgetting about $X$ entirely. If we try to construct $Y^{*}$ and that use it to construct a $wk$ topology to endow $Y$ with, is $(Y,wk_{Y}) = (X^{*}, wk_{X}^{*})$?

Here $wk_{Y}$ denotes the weak topology on $Y$ which was constructed from the linear functionals on $Y$ and $wk_{X}^{*}$ is the weak star topology on $X$ as usual.

I don't necessarily require a proof, but I would like some insight as to what is going on. If I were to distill this into a single question, it would be whether or not I can just "add stars" in the naive way I want and have it all work out?

Edit: I think I created a weird notational blunder by defining $Y:=  (X^{*},\lVert \cdot\rVert)$ then later trying to write $(Y,wk_{Y})$, but I don't know how else to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to me. Do you mean to ask if the weak-star topology on the dual $X^*$ is the same as the weak topology on it? If so, this is not true. The weak star topology is the smallest topology to make the elements of the embedding of $X \hookrightarrow X^{**}$ continuous, whereas the weak topology is the smallest topology to make the elements of $X^{**}$ continuous. Therefore, the weak-star topology is generally weaker (fewer open sets) than the weak topology. There are conditions where they coincide, however (such as reflexivity).

Comment: @AloizioMacedo  I want to start with the dual of $X$, call it $Y$. I would now like to forget that it was ever the dual of $X$ and use the linear functionals on $Y^{*}$ to generate a weak topology for $Y$. Now I want to see if the weak star topology on $X^{*}$ coincides with the weak topology on $Y$.

Essentially, I want to apply the usual process to creating a weak topology on the space $X^{*}$ and then see if this weak topology has the same open sets as the topology defined in the usual manner by defining a weak* topology from $X$.

Comment: Right, then my comment explains exactly what you are asking. If you have any doubt, please ask.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I think I have a better understanding now, but just to double check if I am following correctly, would it be enough to have a non-reflexive space that is isometrically isomorphic to its double dual?